# Replace Node in linkedList

Tags: java, replace, linked-list

I'm trying to replace a node inside a linkedList

like this :

```
public void setNodeAt(int i, NodeShape nodeToChange) {
    if(i == 0){
        nodeToChange.setNextNode(firstNode.getNext());
        firstNode = nodeToChange;
        return;
    }

    NodeShape previousNode = getNodeAt(i - 1);
    NodeShape sTmp = previousNode.getNext().getNext();
    nodeToChange.setNextNode(sTmp);
    previousNode.setNextNode(nodeToChange);
}
```

I don't understand why but at the end of the method the node has for next node itself ...

[image]

Comment: I believe that this method has already been written for you -- It's called the 'set' method for linked lists

Comment: yeah but i can't use any existing collection from the java api